# d3 select elements having no id

Tags: dom, d3.js, css-selectors

I have the following DOM

```
<g id="s1s2" class="contact">
    <g class="baseCircle">
        <path id="s1s2_base">
    </g>
    <path >
    <path >
</g>
```

and I would like to get all the paths that have no id.
I have tried

```
d3.select('g#s1s2.contact').selectAll('path:not(id)');
```

which returns all paths:

```
[[path#s1s2_base, path, path]]
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is a bit off. To select all elements not having an `id` attribute you can use `"path:not([id])"`. Note, how this uses additional square brackets indicating that this is actually an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```js
console.log(d3.selectAll("path:not([id])").size());   // 2
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<svg>
  <g id="s1s2" class="contact">
      <g class="baseCircle">
          <path id="s1s2_base"/>
      </g>
      <path />
      <path />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

In D3, the `.attr()` function without the second argument can be used as a *getter*.

Thus, select all `<path>` and filter them, eliminating those that have an ID. In that case,

```
!d3.select(this).attr("id")
```

Will return `true` for such paths.

```js
var noId = d3.selectAll("path").filter(function() {
    return !d3.select(this).attr("id")
});

console.log(noId.attr("class"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <path id="foo" class="hasID"></path>
 <path id="bar" class="hasID"></path>
 <path class="noID"></path>
 <path id="baz" class="hasID"></path>
</svg>
```

**PS**: as the S.O. snippet is freezing when trying to `console.log` a D3 selection, here is a fiddle with the same code: https://jsfiddle.net/n615hqub/

Answer (score -1):

You have to change `id` of the id of the element you don't want to select:

```
d3.select('g#s1s2.contact').selectAll('path:not(#s1s2_base)');
```